# std::vector difference of behaviour between msvc and gcc on operator[] after reserve, which is right?

Tags: c++

[This snippet of code](https://ideone.com/F2dBjM) fails miserably using msvc (out of bound error) but appears to work fine with both gcc and clang. What is the correct behaviour ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v[i] = i * 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] <<  " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: perfect example of *undefined*

Comment: Don't use magic numbers! std::vector has a size meber function.

Comment: That was just for the example manni66 ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is undefined. [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) only reserves memory, but doesn't affect the size of the container. Maybe you wanted to use [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)?

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.resize(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    v[i] = i * 2;
}
```

though in this case you could've written

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    v[i] = i * 2;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `reserve` in concert with [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    v.push_back(i * 2);
}
```

Comment: A bit of background there, it was a typo made a long time ago which never caused any issue since we were using only gcc / clang. When we ported our code on windows we encountered this crash. The fix was indeed obvious but I was wondering what was the _correct behaviour_ here.

Comment: @Zouch Well then, the answer to that question is: both are correct ;)

Comment: @Zouch undefined is undefined.

Comment: what is `reserve` even good for, I mean in your 3rd example it's seems useless if you `push_back` anyway.

Comment: @StackDanny that's an another question ;) `reserve` guarantees that you won't have reallocations (more formally: references and iterators won't be invalidated) until you hit the reserved size (which may be higher than you reserved, afaict).

Comment: @StackDanny  It means that the underlying buffer has been allocated with enough space to hold at least 10 elements.  So push_back (in this case) will not cause a reallocation.

Comment: @StackDanny when you know you will insert like 1000 elements internally the space will be allocated once when you call reserve. When you don't you will reallocate each time the internal capacity has not enough space, which takes time. So reserve before can reduce allocations and copy operations which makes code faster.

Comment: thank you, all for explaining. I think I really could use `reserve` in my projects sometimes. :)

Comment: @StackDanny when you know how many elements you need to insert this should be a "default" to use reserve ;) (also mentioned in `effective stl` by scott meyers if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 3):

Some explanation on what is **undefined** here:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10);
```

`reserve` only "reserves" memory but does not actually change the size of the vector. So when you do

```
v[i] = i * 2;
```

You write an `int` to a place which was not initialized yet because the vector has still the size 0.

What happens in those cases is **undefined**. Compilers and library implementations here are free to do what they like.

What is defined though is that the **size** of the vector **does not** change by `reserve` (but by `resize`) but the **capacity** (which is something different).